# como puedo mostrar el dato de mi columna delegacion solo una vez sin mostrarlo en mi tabla

Tags: php

Muestro el codigo donde realizo mi consulta por delegaciones, y me los muestra en una tabla, lo que deseo es que el campo delegaciones no me los muestre en la tabla ya que los datos son los mismos, es decir las misma delegacion, asi que quiero que aparezca en la parte de arriba de mi tabla solo una vez, para que el usuario sepa que todos los datos de la tabla pertenecen a dicha delegacion!! espero que me puedan ayudar, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
$conect = new mysqli("localhost", "onethost_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "onethost_MPA");
$v3=$_POST['codigo'];
//$sql= "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
$sql = "SELECT * from TablaNinos inner join InformacionGeneral ON TablaNinos.Id_General=InformacionGeneral.Id_General WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado)){
?>     
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Id_nino"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Nombre"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Cargo"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Curp"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Telefono"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha_registro"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Id_General"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Delegacion"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Parroquia"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_apoyo"]?></td>
        </tr>   
      <?php
 }

?>
```

Comment: Pdeberias poner la como haces la consulta

Comment: muestra tu codigo como texto, lee [ask] y mejora tu pregunta

Comment: srJJ mi consulta esta en la segunda imagen, hago un inner join y la primera imagen es como me muestra los datos en la tabla.

Comment: eyllanesc gracias voy a checar como hacer eso, soy nuevo aquí

Comment: @JoseLuisSantiagoPacheco puedes pegar todo tu código y una vez este lo seleccionas y das clic en el ícono `{}` del editor de textos para que tenga formato

Comment: @AlfredoPaz gracias, ya lo hago

Comment: Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con esta situacion.  quiero que cuando el usuario haga su consulta por delegacion se le muestre en la parte de arriba delegacion: el que seleccione y abajito la tabla con los demas datos.

Comment: ¿cuando dices arriba te refieres afuera de la tabla o al inicio de la tabla?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz afuera de la tabla

Comment: y no bastaría que fuera del código del table hagas esto por ejemplo `<div><?php echo $fila["Delegacion"]?></div>`

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya lo intente pero me lo muestra varias veces por que esta dentro del while

Comment: solo quiero que me lo muestre solo una vez, cuando intento como tu dices, me lo muestra muchas veces

Comment: @AlfredoPaz gracias por responderme, ya quedo solucionado.

Comment: comparte la solución en la zona de respuestas, sirve que ayudas a otros usuarios con la misma duda y te la calificamos

Comment: esta bien solo busco la zona de respuestas y la comparto! muchas gracias

Comment: justo debajo de esta publicación puedes colocar tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

les comparto la solución amigos, espero que alguien le sirva, solo imprimí con un echo la opción que el usuario seleccionaba a la hora de su búsqueda, ese dato estaba guardado en la variable $s3, lo imprimi fuera del while.

```
<?php
$conect = new mysqli("localhost", "onethost_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "onethost_MPA");
$v3=$_POST['codigo'];
//$sql= "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
$sql = "SELECT * from TablaNinos inner join InformacionGeneral ON TablaNinos.Id_General=InformacionGeneral.Id_General WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado)){
?>    
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Nombre"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Cargo"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Curp"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Telefono"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha_registro"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Parroquia"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_apoyo"]?></td>
        </tr>   
      <?php
 }

?>
<p>Delegacion:<? echo $v3?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si eliminás el `td` que tiene las delegaciones y incorporás el dato en la variable `$delegacion`, después podés utilizarlo por fuera del `while`. Sin embargo, sin el código completo es difícil ordenarlo para lograr lo que querés hacer, ya que falta el resto de la tabla.
Tal vez sea necesario concatenar los resultados en otra variable e imprimirla luego, pero esto ya depende del resto del código.

```
<?php
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado)){
    $delegacion = $fila["Delegacion"];
?>     
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Id_nino"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Nombre"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Cargo"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Curp"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Telefono"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha_registro"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Id_General"]?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $fila["Parroquia"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_apoyo"]?></td>
        </tr>   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo!! ya di con la solución muchas gracias.